# How to transfer data from Node js to html file?

Tags: node.js

I am new bie in node js can anyone tell how to transfer data from nodejs file to html file....
Like  for example :
If  html page takes first name and last name as text and pass to node js..
..then how can nodejs transfer full name(first name +last name)  to same html file and show it there

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use Node.js for that? Just use Javascript to concatenate first name and last name.. I suggest you try to study more about what each technology is used for

Answer (score 0):

In javascript have string concatenate functionality

```
var firstName="Rahul"

var lastName="Dey"

name =firstName+" "+lastName   // Rahul Dey
```

this is one approach

otherwise, You have to create an API in node js, which is taken the two value as a parameter and return a response of concatenated string. But it is not a good approach.
So go with the first One.